# Need to setup project environment from Docker image

Tags: visual-studio-code, dockerfile, dock

I am new to the VS Code. I have a Docker image, which has the dependencies, and a project folder. I need to dependencies from that image to work on my project.

I have looked into too many tutorials and documentation but nothing is working for me.
All go to 'Add Development Environment Configutaion Files' and then two options whether use 'Docker File' or 'pre defined configurations'.

I, on the other hand, need to create env/set interpretor from the local docker image.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.